# USB Driver - This device cannot start. (Code 10) - Insufficient system resources exist to complete the API

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, device-manager, usb-2

I've been tired trying find a solution,
My USB controllers have a yellow exclamation sign in **Device manager** thus any USB I plug into isn't functioning until I remove the driver and reinstall it, and in the next restart it is stopping again and I have to redo all that bad stuff again which sometimes make the computer hang and need to be restarted with the **Reset button**...

I'm using Windows 10 version 1709 build 16299.371

And here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you run SFC? See https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/website-troubleshooting/run-system-file-checker

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'll try that..

Comment: Deleting LowerFilter and UpperFilter of that USB classes in the registry. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\***********

Comment: You can find the class guid from device manager, USB controller properties -> Details -> Class GUID.

Comment: @KarenHu I'll try that..

Comment: @DrMoishePippik SFC didn't help :(

Comment: @KarenHu Thanks, after 2 restarts it seems that your solution worked..
Please answer it for me to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Those registry keys don't even exist for me, yet I am facing this issue. Is anything else known about this?

Comment: In my case, I needed to use a different USB port (the one on the front wasn't powerful enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from member [Karen Hu](https://superuser.com/users/722169/karen-hu):

Deleting LowerFilter and UpperFilter values of that USB classes in the registry. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class***********

You can find the class guid from device manager, USB controller properties -> Details -> Class GUID.