# HP Probook 640 G3 LAN issue "Device Cannot Start – Error 10"

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, lan, hp

I've got two refurbished "HP ProBook 640 G3" with LAN "error 10" "Device cannot start"
The problematic LAN device is **PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15D8&SUBSYS_82AA103C**
Which is **Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) i209-v**

- **Model:** HP ProBook 640 G3
- **Product Name:** HP ProBook 640 G3
- **Processor 1 Type:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
- **Memory Size**  8192 MB
- **Product Family**   103C_5336AN HP ProBook
- **System BIOS Version**  P83 Ver. 01.44  09/13/2022
- **ME Firmware Version**  11.8.70.3626
- **Video BIOS Version**   Intel(R) GOP Driver [9.0.1056]
- **Integrated MAC Address 1** F4-30-B9-XX-XX-XX
- *Asset Tracking Number*
- *Ownership Tag*
- **Native OS Firmware Update Service**    *Enable
- **BIOS Rollback Policy**     *Unrestricted Rollback to older BIOS
- **Manufacturing Programming Mode**   *Lock
- **Host Based MAC Address**   *Custom
- **HBMA Factory MAC Address**     F4-30-B9-XX-XX-XX
- **HBMA System MAC Address**  F4-30-B9-XX-XX-XX
- **HBMA Custom MAC Address**  F4-30-B9-XX-XX-XX
- **Pre-boot HBMA Support**    *Enable
- **Windows HBMA Support**     *Enable
- **Single NIC Operation (Disable All Other NICs when HBMA is active on one NIC)** *Disable
- **Reuse Embedded LAN Address**   *Enable
- **HBMA Priority List**

  - USB NIC Dongle:HP External Adapter :0BDA_8153**
  - USB NIC Dongle:HP USB-C Travel Dock :17E9_4352
  - USB NIC Dongle:HP USB Travel Dock :17E9_4351
  - USB NIC Dongle:HP 3005pr :17E9_430A
  - USB NIC Dongle:HP Universal pr :17E9_4327
  - Embedded NIC:Intel (non-vPro) :8086_15D8:103C_82AA
- **Embedded LAN controller**  *Enable

I have tried the following:
0.  Latest signed driver installed is: 12.19.2.45 (30/01/2022) from Intel

1. (Uninstall/Reinstall) & Restart the latest drivers from HP and Intel Websites.
2. Disable & Enable device
3. Reset the Bios default settings (multiple times)
4. Rollback Bios to the previous version.
5. Update Bios to the latest version (P83 Ver. 01.44  09/13/2022)
6. Windows 10 22H2 (19045.2251) with Latest updates to this moment of writing this thread.
7. Use Custom Host Based MAC Address F4-30-B9-XX-XX-XX (XX-XX-XX are other hex numbers)
8. No *UpperFilters*/*LowerFilters* under LAN device GUID in registry  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class"
9. "msdt -id DeviceDiagnostic" didn't resolve the Code 10 error.
10. "sfc /scannow" & "DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth" & "DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth" also didn't find any issues.

**Update1:** Upon further checking, here is what I found from *Intel SSU tool*:

```
      Product Type:"Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V"

      Service Name:"e1dexpress"

      Status:"Disabled"
```

But the onboard LAN adapter I219-V is enabled in device manager with yellow exclamation mark.

**Update 2:** I used BootUtil v1.39.05.5 (*Intel(R) Ethernet Flash Firmware Utility*) and the result is as follows:

```
 Port Network Address Location Series  WOL Flash Firmware    Version 
 ==== =============== ======== ======= === ================= =======
 1    FA30B9XXXXXX    0:31.6   Gigabit N/A FLASH Not Present
```

What's the problem with this LAN Adapter? Why I'm getting this "Code 10" Error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, this [SO answer](https://superuser.com/a/1319763/163333) should fix it.
[image]
[image]

Deleting LowerFilter and UpperFilter values of the USB classes in the registry should fix the problem, don't forget to reboot your OS after.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not apply in my case, I've mentioned it in the post

Comment: @M.A. Yes, I've noticed that, but I hope that you've searched for the correct class name. Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, yes the LAN adapter class GUID in registry does not have neither Upperfilers nor LowerFilters